# how to access global variable inside onerror event of audio object

Tags: angular, audio, onerror

I want to access isDisabled variable from audio.onerror function and want to reset the value of isDisabled but unable to set it.

```
public isDisabled: boolean = false;
private verifyPrompt(url: string): boolean{
           let audio = new Audio(this.promptMessageUrl);
           this.isDisabled = 
           audio.load;
        audio.onerror = function(e){
            this.isDisabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the`function` keyword and use arrow function notation `()=>`.

```
audio.onerror = (e) => {
    this.isDisabled = true;
}
```